# xed can't jump line when xcode is opened

Tags: xcode

I want to open file with Xcode and jump to a specified line from another application.

I've tried `open -a Xcode [file name]` but can't find `--args` for Xcode to jump line.

Currently, I'm using `xed --line [line no] [filename]`.

It works ok when xcode is not running. But it won't jump line when xcode is opened.

How can I fix this problem, or is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i find a solution to fix this.
https://medium.com/xcblog/xed-the-lightweight-text-editor-for-xcode-269aae5b2a77

Passing the — line and line number will select the line number in the **last file** opened. This would be useful to quickly jump to the line number in the given file.

run
"xed -x [file name]"
and then run
"xed -x -l [line no]"
to select the line number in the last file opened.